# PWM with MOSFet- make it linear

Tags: microcontroller, led, mosfet, pwm

there maybe wrong assumption in my question , so forgive me, i am here to learn .

So controlling a light(LED) with MCU that outputs PWM, into a MOSFET N-CHANNEL, as described in this little image:[image]

so if i check the voltage in the gate, i can see clearly that it goes linearly up from 0 to 3.3V . (vcc is 5v)

But when you look at it, the led is really not dimming linearly at all, and has these steps.
As we know the `ID is proportional to (VGS-VT)^2` , and that means if the gate goes up linearly , the output will be nonlinear .

But, i do want a completely linear experience, and i was wondering a few things :

1. because `ID is proportional to (VGS-VT)^2`, i can put the voltage in the gate to be square(V), and so when i move up a **linear slider**, the output may be linear (?? )

2.the fact that i goes from 0 to -3V, maybe has to do with the specific MOSFET, that create this effect?

Bottom line, i see all the time,that you can use a MOSFET to dim a light, but he is not a linear animal ,and usually these circuits dont add any other parts to the circuit .

Comment: If the MOSFET isn't saturating then you're using the wrong MOSFET.

Comment: Why is your gate voltage doing anything resembling "goes linearly up from 0 to 3.3V". You should have a square wave there which alternates between 0 and 5V (your vcc).

Comment: @brhans , as you know, a square wave in PWM high frequency , is exactly like linear voltage if you change the duty cycle. the output INDEED as the vcc, which is 3.3V, because thats my design .

Comment: @Curnelious How high is your frequency? Are you measuring the RMS?

Comment: @Curnelious The way a PWM is typically used to drive a MOSFET is most definitely not in any way "exactly like linear voltage". The PWM should be driving the MOSFET hard into saturation and fully off for each cycle. In this way the MOSFET is then "PWMing" your load, which then appears much the same as a "linear voltage". The point being - your MOSFET is supposed to be operating as a switch and not in any in-between state.

Comment: As described, I don't understand where the PWM is??  Where are the pulses you're changing the width of??

Comment: *Pedantic mode on*: For a MOSFET operating as a switch, you want to be in the *linear* region. The *saturation* region is the constant-current region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are taking a wrong approach here for designing your requirements. Typically, if you want to control the LED intensity with PWM, you should make sure that the PWM high voltage (3.3V in your case) will open the FET completely (turn it on, bring to saturation region), while the low voltage will close it (turn it off). In that way the LED will blink with your PWM frequency, and the duty cycle will affect how much time out of the total it will be lit. If the frequency is high enough, the flickering won't be visible, and you will get nice dimming effect.

Comment: Just a comment- you're not the only person to refer to opening a MOSFET (in the sense of turning it on). Isn't there some cognitive dissonance with 'open circuit'?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Accepted. Added some disambiguation.

Comment: Well,thats wrong.It seems that you dont understand what i am saying, or that i don't explain well . The led shouldn't blink and i don't want to take the MOSFET in and out of the saturation, the PWM frequency is high (500Hz) , and the duty cycle changes ,so you get a "DC" voltage that changes from 0 to VCC . What you actually do, is to work inside the saturation mode, and change Id of the FET,to drive the led current linearly.

Comment: @Curnelious (1) 500Hz is not high. (2) This is exactly the way to dim an LED (believe me, it's my profession, and I have some experience).

Comment: 500Hz is high enough and your eye wouldn't see it unless you are a robot(?) . The FET cant really follow your PWM, because VGS is changes ,while VDS is const, so your equation is non linear.

Comment: @Curnelious Forget about equations. When driven with a voltage that is high enough to get it to saturation and frequency low enough (and 500Hz is low enough) to ignore the transition effects, the FET is effectively a controlled switch. So just think about it this way.

Comment: This is so wrong. I cant ignore equations.Did you ever see a MOSFET graph ? the reason you use PWM for dimming, is because with the D.C you get the effect of linear from "digital" square wave .Anyway, its not seems to go anywhere, and you didn't even provide an answer, because bottom line, this is how its done,question is,not if you can do it, but what MOSFET you choose, and how voltages affect this(USING THE EQUATIONS )

Comment: Ok, I am here not for arguing. I just know. You - don't. This is why you are asking and I am answering. If you think you know better - why asking? If you look up to the comments on your question, you will notice @brhans commented exactly the same thing. So you can take it or leave it.

Comment: @Curnelious This is the normal way to dim an LED with PWM. Eugene is correct (as are all the other folks who made similar comments).

Comment: @Curnelious I think you are confusing the ohmic region with saturation and cut-off regions of a MOSFET. A MOSFET driven by a PWM signal will either be in saturation (a short-circuit), or in cut-off (an open-circuit), **never** in ohmic (i.e. linear) region. What you are actually doing with a PWM signal is turn on your LED at **full brightness** for a given ammount of time, and then turn it completly off. Do this fast enough, and your eyes won't be able to tell the difference between a very fast blinking bright light or a constant, not-so-bright light.

Comment: This "averaging" you talk about has nothing to do with the MOSFET's linear region. In fact, it has nothing to do with MOSFETs. You could achieve the same result with relays switching very fast, or even by just you pressing a push button switch very fast.